# Required any solution for how to recover old deleted file in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to make an app which will recover the old deleted files like Photos, Videos, and other types of files. Unfortunately, I have researched over the internet but couldn't find the proper solution or any sort of algorithm from where I can get an idea of how this recovery works.

The solution can be in any language Java or Kotlin both will work fine. There are so many mobile apps that help you to recover the old deleted files, so there might be some solution.

One more thing is there we have to write in Android NDK to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, Android does not support this.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how is this possible that many recovery apps are available on Google Play store?

Comment: I expect they are mostly junk. A few might work but make assumptions about Android's implementation that might not work across all Android OS versions and device manufacturers (and even these hopefully require root privileges). By "does not support this", I mean that when you `delete()` a `File` in Android, it is deleted, not simply moved into some "trash can" from which you can recover it. The closest thing would be the various options to try to recover deleted files in Linux, and that usually requires superuser (root) permissions.